# Return starting address of a data array

Tags: c, pointers, vector

I am trying to write a function that returns the starting address of a data array.

```
    // Return starting address of the data array
    data_t *get_vec_start(vec_ptr v)
    {
        data_t *address = v->data[0];
        return address;
    }
```

I am receiving an error that says:

```
vec.c: In function ‘get_vec_start’:
vec.c:75:20: error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘data_t *’ using type ‘data_t’
data_t *address = v->data[0];
                ^
make: *** [vec.o] Error 1
```

I am new to C and do not understand the error message. Thank you.

Comment: I believe `v->data[0]` returns the value of the first cell in the array, not its address in memory. Therefore, it is not a `data_t *` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either `return v->data;` or `return &(v->data[0]);` work.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign the actual data to the variable `address` instead of assigning the actual address of the `0th` element!

Try something like this:

```
data_t* address = &(v->data[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It says right there: incompatible types when initializing type ‘data_t *’ using type ‘data_t’.

You have to assign the address of the array.

```
data_t* a = &v->data[0] ;
```

or

```
data_t* a = v->data ;
```

v->data[0] is of type `data_t` and &v->data[0] is `data_t*`